# How to correctly intercept system calls in the Linux kernel 5.*?

Tags: c, linux, hook, kernel-module

There was a need to write a kernel module, with a hook for exec. I found a way with `sys_calls_table` and `lsm`. As I understand it, `sys_calls_table` is more of a hack than a correct solution, and I did not find normal examples for `lsm`.

How to correctly intercept a system call in modern kernel versions? I will be very happy with examples.

Comment: As I understand it, Linux deliberately does not provide any supported feature for intercepting system calls at runtime.  I believe this is a conscious design decision by the kernel developers.  So there is no "correct" approach, and any way of doing it is by definition a hack.

Comment: I think the idea is that if you want to modify the behavior of a system call, you should patch and recompile the kernel itself, instead of writing a module.

Comment: I do hope that init wont get beyond runlevel#1. (basically, I trust on it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no correct way to do this.

LSM (Linux Security Modules) doesn't support system calls interception,
with LSMs you need the implemented some of the functions listed at [lsm_hooks_defs.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/lsm_hook_defs.h).

There are two alternatives ways to intercept system calls which I'm aware of:

1. Hook the `sys_call_table` which can be obtained, and overwrite the pointers with your new function:

   ```
   unsigned long *sys_call_table_ptr = kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
   unsigned long cr0 = read_cr0();
   write_cr0(cr0 & ~x86_CR0_WP);
   sys_call_table_ptr[__NR_getpid] = new_getpid;
   write_cr0(cr0);
   ```
2. Using kprobe: Syscall functions name expands with the prefix `__do_sys_`    (see [__SYSCALL_DEFINEx](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L238)).
   For example, kprobe on `__do_sys_finit_module` (or any other syscall you want) as follow:

   ```
   static struct kprobe kp = {
       .symbol_name    = "__do_sys_finit_module",
   };

   static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) {
       // do your logic
       // obtain function arguments using register (calling convetion)
   }

   static int __init kprobe_init(void)
   {
       kp.pre_handler = handler_pre;
       ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
       if (ret < 0) {
           printk(KERN_INFO "register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
           return ret;
       }
       printk(KERN_INFO "Planted kprobe at %p\n", kp.addr);
       return 0;
   }

   static void __exit kprobe_exit(void)
   {
       unregister_kprobe(&kp);
       printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe at %p unregistered\n", kp.addr);
   }
   ```

Comment: It seems like kallsyms_lookup_name isn't being exported anymore

Comment: there are multiple ways to export it, kprobe, global parameter and more. read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930059/proper-way-of-getting-the-address-of-non-exported-kernel-symbols-in-a-linux-kern)