# How to allocate executable space in LKM for 5.x?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

It used to be possible to call `__vmalloc` and pass in `PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC` to allocate executable space in older Linux kernels.

I'm using `5.15.55` and `__vmalloc` doesn't even take that parameter anymore, it takes one less.

How do I allocate executable space in LKM for newer kernel versions?

Comment: module_alloc uses `__vmalloc_node_range` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.12/source/kernel/module.c#L2835

Comment: @stark that'd be good to know if only `__vmalloc_node_range` was exported :')

Comment: Seems like the only option you have left right now is `vmap()` (unless you want to [manually find and call non-exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930059/proper-way-of-getting-the-address-of-non-exported-kernel-symbols-in-a-linux-kern)).