# Kernel Module, Call get_futex_key

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, futex

I am working on a Linux kernel module, and I want to call function `get_futex_key`. How can I do this? The eventual goal is to use kernel functions to return a list of threads that hold a given futex.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/write-linux-kernel-module/) to create a "hello world" module. It uses the `printk` function. I understand that it is possible to use `printk` because it is one of the symbols visible to the kernel.

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep printk
...
ffffffff9ebb9c32 T printk
...
```

Function `get_futex_key` is also visible in `/proc/kallsyms`. It is defined in `futex.c`, not `futex.h`. See this [source](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/kernel/futex.c) for example.

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "get_futex_key"
ffffffff9e3223c0 t get_futex_key_refs.isra.11
ffffffff9e322a30 t get_futex_key
```

Assume that `0x20566a0` is a `uaddr` obtained with the use of `strace`.

```
# strace -p  117589
strace: Process 117589 attached
futex(0x20566a0, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, 0xffffffff^Cstrace: Process 117589 detached
```

I have tried the following code as `fut.c`.

```
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros
#include <linux/futex.h>
#include <kernel/futex.c>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("FutexTestAuthor");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Futex Examiner");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    union futex_key key1 = FUTEX_KEY_INIT;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Get futex key\n");
    //futex_key key1 = FUTEX_KEY_INIT;
    get_futex_key(0x20566a0, 0, &key1, VERIFY_READ);
    printk(KERN_INFO "key1 = %p\n", &key1);
    return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up futex module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

**The `Makefile`**

```
obj-m += fut.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

**Output of `make`**

```
# make
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-204-generic/build M=/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-204-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut/fut.o
/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut/fut.c:5:10: fatal error: kernel/futex.c: No such file or directory
 #include <kernel/futex.c>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:340: recipe for target '/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut/fut.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut/fut.o] Error 1
Makefile:1596: recipe for target '_module_/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/myusername/git/LinuxExamples/kernel/fut] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-204-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why are you including -- well, trying to include -- a .c file?

Comment: Including a **source file** (`kernel/futex.c` in your case) is almost always wrong. The function `get_futex_key` is **static** (in the Linux kernel 4.15), it is **not intended** to be called outside of the source file which defines it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_futex_key()` function is not exported by the kernel. You can notice this in two ways:

1. Looking at kernel sources, exported functions usually have a `EXPORT_SYMBOL(name)` after their definition. This one doesn't.
2. In the output of `/proc/kallsyms`, exported functions have an uppercase `T` symbol, while others have a lowercase `t`. This one has the latter.

You cannot create a module that uses `get_futex_key()` directly as it will fail linking since the kernel does not export it. You also cannot and should never include `.c` files in your module, only `.h` (header) files. In fact, most of the times, `.c` files won't even be available for you to include in the first place, but only `.h` files will.

With the above said, you can either [look at the source code of `get_futex_key()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3/source/kernel/futex/core.c#L220) to understand how it works and re-implement part of its functionality in your module, or take a look at this other question for some hacks that will allow you to get ahold of unexported symbols from modules: [Proper way of getting the address of non-exported kernel symbols in a Linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70930059/3889449)