# How to allocate a read-only page in a kernel module via get_zeroed_page/get_free_page?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In a kernel module that is supposed to run on Kernel version >=6.3, I want to allocate a page that is marked as *read only*. So in pseudo-code, something like this:

```c
page = get_free_page();
set_readonly(page);
// Write to page should fail because page is marked as read-only in permission table. 
// Executing page should also fail.
```

I think `set_memory_ro` in `arch/x86/mm/pat/set_memory.c` is what I am looking for, however, the symbol/that function does not seem to be exported. Since `kallsyms_lookup` is disabled, how can I mark my page as read-only in the kernel module?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70934260/18877953) answer regarding using non-exported functions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way without using non-exported functions? A lot of these options require to recompile the kernel (either with added code or different compiler options). I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this unfortunately. I can't seem to find modules that do this either. Seems like you will have to hack your way around it.